# WordPress jQuery Uncaught Reference Error (can't figure it out)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WP site here: http://projects2.yeahcan.com/libdes/

And the carousel (Elastislide) at the bottom is not working. I am getting an error of Uncaught Reference Error and have tried many different things to solve it. I assumed it was something to do with jQuery or js script but after altering the order of script I still can't solve this problem.
Could someone please take a look and see if you could figure it out?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use layerSlider jquery plugin (on line 102) which is not included there

Comment: Sorry; Layerslider is installed but is not showing due to the error. If I disable Layerslider, the error goes away but the carousel still doesn't load/work as it's supposed to.